# Let {$x_{n}$} be a sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ such that $x_{n+1} - x_{n} \geq \frac{1}{n}$. Prove that $x_{n} \rightarrow + \infty$.

Tags: real-analysis

By the assumption of the sequence, we have that $x_{n} \leq x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$.  Let $M =x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$.  Then for every real $M$, we have an integer $N$ such that $n \geq N$ implies that $M \geq x_{n}$.  By definition $x_{n} \rightarrow - \infty$.

I do not know what I am doing wrong here.  It seems that I am following the definition exactly. Also {$x_{n}$} is monotonically increasing so I feel it should go to plus infinity but do not know what to do.

I actually see that $M =x_{n+1} - \frac{1}{n}$ is not every real.  hmmm....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that

$$x_n -x_1 \geqslant \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k}.$$

Show that the harmonic series on the RHS diverges as $n \to \infty$ using

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2^n-1}\frac1{k}> \frac1{2} + \frac1{4} + \frac1{4} + \frac1{8} + \frac1{8}+\frac1{8}+\frac1{8} + \ldots = \sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2}= \frac{n}{2}.$$

For any $K > 0$ choose $M \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $x_1 + M/2 > K$. Then for all $n \geqslant 2^M$ we have

$$x_n \geqslant x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{k} \geqslant x_1 + \sum_{k=1}^{2^M-1}\frac1{k}> x_1+ \frac{M}{2}> K,$$

and

$$\lim_{n \to \infty}x_n = +\infty$$

Comment: I get it now thanks!

Comment: @Tim: You're welcome.

Comment: @Tim: I added above to answer your subsequent questions about why $x_n \to \infty$.

Comment: oh cool that's nifty!  how does one come up with that?  I am having struggling with my creativity on proofs.  i cannot think outside the definition.

Comment: Thanks. Work through a lot of examples and exercises after learning the definitions and basic theorems. Eventually you learn some tricks that can be applied again and again. The telescoping series / sequence equivalence is often used to find the sum of a complicated-looking series when the limit of the sequence is obvious. Here we use it in reverse.

Answer (score 1):

From definition  $x_{2}\geq x_{1}+\frac{1}{1}$, then  $x_{3}\geq x_{2}+\frac{1}{2}\geq x_{1}+\frac{1}{1}+\frac{1}{2}$. In general you have that $$x_{n+1}\geq x_{1}+ \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{n},$$ then, as $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}=\infty ,$$ we have that $\lim_{x\to \infty} x_{n}=\infty$.

Comment: Thank you that makes perfect sense!

Comment: quick question, doesn't the RHS limit being infinity only show that $x_{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$.  How do we then jump to saying $x_{n} \rightarrow \infty$ since $x_{n} \leq x_{n+1}$.

Comment: Well, limit of `(x_{n})_{n=1}^{\infty}` is the same as limit of `(x_{n+1})_{n=1}^{\infty}` because you are adding a finite number of elements to the sequence, in this case one, the first one. In general $`\lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n} = \lim_{n\to \infty} x_{n+k}`$, for any k.

Answer (score 0):

Use telescoping series to get $$x_{n+1}-x_1\ge \sum^{n}_{k=1} \frac{1}{k}$$ and apply lim both sides

Comment: $lim_{n \to \infty} (x_{n+1}-x_{1}) \geq lim_{n \to \infty} (\frac{1}{n})$.  So $ \infty \geq 0$.  what does this tell us about $x_{n}$?

Comment: RHS is divergent series i.e it is going to infinity, so LHS must go to infinity!

Comment: I get it now, thank you!!

Comment: your welcome,if you're done with this problem then think about this one, Does $|x_{n+1}-x_n|<\frac{1}{n}$ imply $x_n \to \infty$?

Comment: hmm..I have a similar homework problem to that.  I will repost after I get to that.  Thanks!

Comment: quick question, doesn't the RHS limit being infinity only show that $x_{n+1} \rightarrow \infty$.  How do we then jump to saying $x_{n} \rightarrow \infty$ since $x_{n} \leq x_{n+1}$.